# Eclipse (java) - Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

So im getting the msg "Person cannot be resolved to a type" at Person p1,p2... and at P1,p2,p3 = new person...

Have been googling like crazy but im very new with programming and with Eclipse so im really lost at fixing this problem. I tried using this code with Sublime Text and i did actually get the same errors so is maybe the actual code the problem or is Eclipse bugging?

Thanks!

```
public class Ptest2main2{
public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Person p1, p2, p3;

    p1 = new Person ("Kalle anka", "123 ocean drive, orlando florida", 79);
    p2 = new Person ("Wile E Cotoye", "15 Acme Road, Hollywood California", 67);
    p3 = new Person ("Elmer Fudd", "Loony Toones Ave, bubank, California");

    System.out.printf("\n%-18s%-40s%s\n", "namn", "adress", "alder");
    System.out.printf (p1.skrivUt() + '\n');
    System.out.printf (p2.skrivUt() + '\n');
    System.out.printf (p3.skrivUt() + "\n\n");

 }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you haven't imported `Person` class into your `Ptest2main2` class.

Comment: Did you write a class called `Person`?  And is it in the same directory as your `Ptest2main2` class?  It probably should be.

Comment: Also, you forgot to say how old Elmer Fudd is.

Comment: @DavidWallace according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmer_Fudd), he's 74.

Comment: @chiastic-security 77

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well you outrank me on rep by a long way so I am loath to get into a debate on something this important, but what makes you say 77? The Wiki page has his first appearance (as Elmer) in 1940. But perhaps he was three years old at the time?

Comment: Import the Person class.

Comment: This could be a different Elmer Fudd.  What do you bet the postman always gets their mail mixed up?

Comment: @chiastic-security *Egghead: Egghead Rides Again (1937)*. And the article states: *In 1937, Tex Avery introduced a new character in his cartoon short Egghead Rides Again.*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The Wikipedia page on Elmer Fudd seems to see that as a kind of proto-Fudd, with the real Fudd kicking off in 1940. But I am way out of my depth. We are into the murkiest depths of the Java language here.

Comment: @chiastic-security I don't think this is the murkiest depths of Java language. It's just about `import`s :). They may become murkier once Java 9 appears with jigsaw and modularity, thought.

Answer (score 2):

`Person` is a class that you're trying to create instances of.

It isn't a standard Java class, which means you need to define it somewhere. Either you just haven't got a `Person` class and you need to create one, or you've got one, but you haven't imported it into this class.

Look at the symbol to the left of the error line in Eclipse. If it's a red cross, that means Eclipse can't think of any way of getting you out of this. If it's a lightbulb superimposed on a red cross, you can click it to get ideas for how to solve it. If there's a `Person` class somewhere that you haven't imported, then Eclipse should help you find it.

Comment: Or, more likely, it exists and was intended to be in the same package, so it wouldn't need to be explicitly imported; but OP decided to work in a new directory, without understanding the implication of doing so.

Comment: @DavidWallace possibly, yes. If the package declaration was wrong, though, then Eclipse would have mentioned it. In any case, I've added something about Eclipse's helpful lightbulbs, and either way it ought to do something useful here.

Comment: Seriously, I suspect that OP is a student, and they haven't learnt about packages yet, so they're just dumping everything in the default package.  If he/she started a new directory for the `Ptest2main2` class, Eclipse won't be able to tell him/her how to find the `Person` class.  If this is the case, then the best advice is "put it in the same directory".